# pip freeze doesn't show anything in Windows installation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I have Python27 installed in Windows 7

I am trying to build a reddit bot [using this tutorial](http://pythonforengineers.com/build-a-reddit-bot-part-1/)

I found instructions on how to install pip for windows from [here](https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation)

The page says that after installing pip, I can use pip freeze to check if the installation went correctly

It says pip freeze should display some information as shown below

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200] (c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation.
>   All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\Username>cd c:\Python27\Scripts
>
> c:\Python27\Scripts>pip freeze
>   antiorm==1.1.1
>   enum34==1.0
>   requests==2.3.0 virtualenv==1.11.6

However pip freeze doesn't show me anything at all  [image]

Did pip install correctly, or is there any problem? Is there any other way i can test proper installation?

Comment: From your linked tutorial: `pip freeze displays the version number of all modules installed in your Python non-standard library; On a fresh install, pip freeze probably won't have much info to show but we're more interested in any errors that might pop up here than the actual content`. You don't have modules installed for it to display.

Comment: so the installation is probably fine? I was expecting it to show some kind of confirmation

Comment: If you want a confirmation, you can `pip install` something like `numpy`. Then, run `pip freeze` again. It is a decent sized package to test if pip is working as expected. If you want to test it even further, you can open a terminal and write "python", then write "import numpy". That should be the complete test of your pip installation.

Comment: @Frederik Thanks that worked :) please post it as an answer so that I can accept

Comment: Sure, glad to help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to test it thoroughly, you can use your actual pip installation to install something. For example, numpy would be a good sized example that can rule many problems out.

`> pip install numpy`

Now, run `pip freeze` again to check if pip is working as expected. It should then have something to show.

If you want to test it even further, you can open a terminal and

```
> python
> import numpy
```

That should be the complete test of your pip installation.

Additionally, whenever I install a new tool in my stack, I like to validate its path with `where <executable name>` (on Windows) and `which <executable name>` (on Linux). There are some compilers like Java that are always conflicting with other installations (like crazy, to the point that a complex setup may sometimes have to inject an absolute path to enforce the use of the correct version).

Also, asking the executable for its version can rule many other problems out. In your case, you can use `pip --version` to check which version you got and compare it to the stable or latest, according to what you want to use.

Answer (score 4):

windows is a confusing piece of software if your coming from a Linux background... the solution that worked for me is the following

```
pip list
```

Comment: Windows is confusing for Linux users? I thought it was the other way around :)

Comment: Please be aware that the problem here is not with the operating system. In the current version (when writing this comment: v22.0.4) pip does what it's intended to: show installed packages. The installation of the Original Post was fresh. Hence listing nothing. You can modify the script with `pip freeze --all` which will lead to `Do not skip these packages in the output: wheel, setuptools, pip, distribute`. You can check the source (https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/22.0.4/src/pip/_internal/commands/freeze.py). Therefore it is just the same with Linux here. WIndows is not always the bad boy...

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that if you only have de default packages in your installation lets say pip, wheel, pip freeze does not have anything to freeze at the moment so that's why dont show anything. try to install a new package then run the command again.